# Python List: Pythonic way to get unique items in given List from a given Set

Tags: python, performance, list

I have a list, which may/may not contain duplicate elements. Given another list/set of Elements, I need a list of all unique elements present in that list.

```
Input: 
input_list = ['android', 'ios', 'android', '', 'none', 'android', 'junk_os']
os_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']
Output:
output = ['android', 'ios']
```

What will be most pythonic and efficient way of doing this ? Length of given list may be around 10, while Os_list is fixed to 3. But this line will be iterated over 10000 times.

Comment: How that out put elements are unique elements?

Comment: Output elements are unique elements present only in given os_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List = ['android', 'ios', 'android', '', 'none', 'android']
OS_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']

y=set(List)
print [i for i in OS_list if i in y]
```

You can use `set` here which is `O(1)`.

The fastest though is (for smaller `List` having upto 600-700 elements)

```
List = ['android', 'ios', 'android', '', 'none', 'android']
OS_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']

[i for i in OS_list if i in List]
```

Time check:

```
s1="""List = ['android', 'ios', 'android', '', 'none', 'android']
OS_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']

[i for i in OS_list if i in List]"""


s2="""List = ['android', 'ios', 'android', '', 'none', 'android']
OS_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']
set(List).intersection(OS_list)"""

print timeit.timeit(stmt=s1,number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s2,number=1000)
```

Output:

```
0.000895947527903
0.00130528204537
```

Comment: What do you need the conversion to a set for?

Comment: @Falko `if i in y` there if you search in list its `O(n)` but if `y` is a `set` its `O(1)`

Comment: I see. But the conversion is O(n), I guess. (At least you have to look at each element once.)

Comment: timing 5 elements is not really an accurate reflection of the huge difference between using a set for lookups and a list, you are taking quadratic vs linear performance.

Comment: And those timings are not accurate. You shouldn't be profiling things that aren't part of the loop in question. We know os_list is a constant and you don't want to muddy the timings by putting the input_list creation in there.

Comment: Searching for unique elements in a list is `O(n^2)` in your brute-force solution. It can be optimized to `O(nlogn)`, but that's the best you can do with lists. Hashing does take `O(n*m)`, where `m` is the average word length, but then the filtration will take `O(n)`, hence you end up with ~ `O(n)` with a big constant, because you only do hashing once. So, I would recommend you to update the statement in your post. It is misleading. You should point that the `set`-based algorithm will be better with bigger inputs.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i ran the tests again with `List` having `600,700` elements.It was again faster.Is there some mistake i m making

Comment: @EliKorvigo updated.I guess this should be enuf for OP.

Comment: If you try moving the interesting elements to the end of LIst and completely removing to handle the worst case, the results should be different

Answer (score 3):

You could use sets to do this

```
set(os_list).intersection(input_list)
```

Edit Since the os_list is fixed you may as well have that stored as a set:

```
os_list = {'android', 'ios', 'windows'}

# then it's a little less work to do each time in the loop
output = os_list.intersection(input_list)
```

Profiling

```
# me
os_set = {'android', 'ios', 'windows'}
%timeit os_set.intersection(input_list)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 323 ns per loop

# vks
os_list = ['android', 'ios', 'windows']
%timeit [i for i in os_list if i in input_list]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 550 ns per loop
```

Using Padraic Cunningham's method you can avoid the function lookup and scrape a little more performance out of it. As a bonus it ends up looking like a function name that makes sense.

```
os_set = {'android', 'ios', 'windows'}
unique_valid_devices = os_set.intersection

%timeit output_list = unique_valid_devices(input_list)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 290 ns per loop
```

Comment: time complexity of intersection ?

Comment: @SameerPidadi this is slower than the list method.

Comment: @vks not on my machine? 779 ns for your list method vs 324 ns for my intersection

Comment: Just seen your updated method (without adding the set component). Comes out as 536 ns on my machine, so still slightly slower.

Comment: @AidanKane i have update my code.Can you please check if i m doing something wrong..

Comment: I'm cheating? :) Not really - I start with the os_list as a set and assume that's not part of the loop.

Comment: For small input the regular list comp is always going to be fast,  the intersection method call alone is going to is going to be costly in comparison to the list comp, adding times for when no elements in os_list are in input_list should show the set approach to definitely be faster, also adding `si = os_set.intersection` and `si(os_list)` should be faster again

Comment: Have updated with your optimisation. Shaves a little more time off.

Comment: I am still running tests.Ran a test with list having 600-700 elemets.Still the non set method was faster :( Probably as Padraic said i will have to move the interesting elements down the list to make sure it take some time there

Comment: Why are you increasing the size of the input list to 700 items? The question specifies that it will be around 10 items. And like I said on your answer - you're not actually profiling the important code.